# Assign aliases to files with build action 'Resource'

Tags: wpf

The application fetches weather data and displays received data including the appropriate icon. Multiple weather codes will use the same icon, e.g `Light rain` and `Heavy rain`. I'd like to avoid creating a code mapper which would return what icon should be used for given code.

Is it possible to "alias" WPF resources so they can be accessed under multiple names, but take up space of single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to "alias" WPF resources so they can be accessed under multiple names, but take up space of single file?

No, each resource must have has a unique name so you should either copy the resource or write some code to that looks up the appropriate resource.

An icon doesn't take up much space so the former approach shouldn't be an issue. You shouldn't create issues that aren't there :)

Comment: Considering the icons are animated gifs with the approximate size of ~150kb and there are around 100 states which are mapped to 10 icons, copying them would significantly increase the app size (~13mb). I'll just go with the manual mapping then.